# Choosing Polynomial Order w/ TS Data

Tags: time-series, econometrics

I have a simple time-series data set where I'm going to run a polynomial regression, in r, with a single predictor. My issue is, with time-series, what is the appropriate method in choosing the polynomial's order? I haven't been able to find much online except for K-Fold Cross Validation which is not applicable with TS data. I've seen a similar methodology to the K-Fold method, which is used with time-series, which entails splitting the data on a rolling basis but I'd like to know what else I should look into.

My initial thought before doing any research was to look to AIC.